# Is there an iOS equivalent for createOrUpdateAllFromJson?

Tags: ios, realm

The Java version of Realm has a very useful method:

```
createOrUpdateAllFromJson(RealmObject,JSONArray)
```

which takes an array of JSON objects, and sticks them all in the database, nicely handling the create or update logic.

Is there an equivalent capability in the iOS version of Realm?  If not, what's the best way to achieve the equivalent functionality?

Comment: Swift or Objective-c?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is direct counterpart to this method in the Cocoa-based bindings, but you can just iterate over your array and provide the values to the methods, which handle dictionaries or arrays describing each a single model object.

#### Swift

via [`Realm.create(_, value: _, update: _`)](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRdq_CS_6Object_FS0_FTMq_5valuePSs9AnyObject_6updateSb_q_):

```
let objects = jsonArray.map { realm.create(MyRealmObject.self, value: $0, update: true) }
```

#### Objective-C

via [`+[RLMObject createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc%28cs%29RLMObject%28cm%29createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:):

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *jsonDict in jsonArray) {
    RLMObject *myRealmObject = [MyRealmObject createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:jsonDict];
    [objects addObject:myRealmObject];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw this and read it as creating a single object from an array, where the array values are in the same order as defined by the RLMObject properties. Can it take an array of JSON objects as in the Java version?

Comment: No, there is no method to do that directly. I corrected my answer to reflect and provided some samples how you can achieve the same for future reference.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume that whole block of code would be wrapped in a begin/commit transaction?

Comment: Yes, that's required.